# codeigniter active record get last 10 records and sort ASC

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I would like to know if this SQL statement is done in Codeigniter active record.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT * 
FROM chat 
WHERE (userID = $session AND toID = $friendID) 
OR (userID = $friendID AND toID = $session)  
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 10
) AS `table` ORDER by id ASC
```

Comment: Yes. Here's how: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

Answer (score 9):

You have to use the `_compile_select()` and `_reset_select()` methods of the active record class.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('chat');
$this->db->where("(userID='{$session}' AND toID='{$friendID}')");
$this->db->or_where("(userID='{$friendID}' AND toID='{$session}')");
$this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
$this->db->limit('10');

$subQuery = $this->db->_compile_select();

$this->db->_reset_select();

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from("{$subQuery} AS table");
$this->db->order_by('id', 'ASC');

$query = $this->db->get();
```

Unfortunately, in CI 2.0+, `_compile_select()` and `_reset_select()` are protected methods. Bummer. You'll have to follow [this tutorial](http://www.simonemms.com/2011/03/18/extending-the-codeigniter-database-class/) on extending the DB driver where you can write methods like the following:

```
function get_compiled_select()
{
    return $this->db->_compile_select();
}

function do_reset_select()
{
    $this->db->_reset_select();
}
```

I would like to take the time to point out that this type of action would be better served by joins. You should consider changing your db structure so that joins are possible and efficient.

Answer (score 1):

This will work, though is not the active record variant.

```
$this->db->query( "SELECT * FROM (
     SELECT * 
     FROM chat 
     WHERE (userID = ? AND toID = ?) 
     OR (userID = ? AND toID = ?)  
     ORDER BY id DESC
     LIMIT 10
     ) AS `table` ORDER by id ASC", array( $session, $friendID, $friendID, $session) );"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use query as:

```
$this->db->select('SELECT * 
     FROM chat 
     WHERE (userID = $session AND toID = $friendID) 
     OR (userID = $friendID AND toID = $session)  
     ORDER BY id DESC
     LIMIT 10') AS `table` ORDER by id ASC', FALSE);
```

Comment: That is not advisable as it doesn't escape the arguments to the query. You run the risk on SQL-injections.

Comment: but it is in codeigniter user guide

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select

Comment: Yes it is IN the user guide, but it's not a good idea to pass variables to an unescaped query. It means someone can manipulate it easily. If someone decided to hijack the $session variable, they could drop all the tables in the DB (if the mysql user has permission). Although, the variables in your example won't be parsed anyway because you used single quotes, so I guess it's OK ;)